# Кто может выполнить у себя код и опубликовать результат?

Tags: php

Дело в том, что криптование и обратное ему действие дает разный результат. На php online платформах не поддерживается функция **m_encrypt**, поэтому не могу проверить.

Нужно разкриптовать строку:

> bc786e/axG88cyGG+NRvv1FcDTIeAQzjty2nTZdW1+evQ2JG00rRXOn2M8S6PWQf3lVPAf1TFmhftqOsUvyKVQ==

подставив в функцию:

```
 function unhashSub($data) {
        $key = md5('crypt');
        $cipher = "rijndael-256";
        $mode = "cbc";
        $data = m_decrypt($data, $key, $cipher, $mode);
        return unserialize($data);

    }

function m_decrypt($data, $key, $cipher, $mode){
 return (string)
   mcrypt_decrypt(
    $cipher,
    substr(md5($key),0,mcrypt_get_key_size($cipher, $mode)),
    base64_decode($data),
    $mode,
    substr(md5($key),0,mcrypt_get_block_size($cipher, $mode))
   );
}
```

Что дает `return`? Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Измени хэш

Comment: Ничего. `m_decrypt()` - это пользовательская функция, а строка еще, судя по всему, обернута в base64 (возможно, внутри `m_encrypt()`)

Comment: Пардон, добавил пользовательскую функцию. `base64_decode` там нужен?

Comment: результат:

    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      int(7)
      ["subType"]=>
      int(0)
      ["template"]=>
      string(3) "btn"
    }